# Numbering bars in Pine editor

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart

How do I number bars in trading view pine editor? For example for an intraday chart of 15mins how can I number the first opening candle as number 1 and second 15min candle as number 2 and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=4
study("Number bars in session")
numBars = 1

t = time('D')

if t == t[1]
    numBars := nz(numBars[1]) + 1
else
    numBars := 1

plot(numBars)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response Michel! Do you happen to know how to code vwap standard deviation bands in pine editor will be really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: No, unfortunatelly, I don't know, but there are functions `stdev` and `vwap` in pine. Maybe you could combine them and get the result.

Comment: No problem mate, the code you suggested is running in some errors it is showing as "mismatched input 'numbars' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'

Comment: Hm, interesting. I couldn't it reprodice, but made little change in the code. Check it out.

Comment: Hey man thanks a ton ! I would now use this to find standard deviation of close price from vwap..... So basically it'll be a moving standard deviation from vwap which will be calculated on every candle........ Or do you suggest any other way to develop a standard deviation band around vwap. Your input will be helpful as I'm new to coding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

See [`bar_index`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_bar_index):

```
//@version=4
study("")
plot(bar_index + 1)
```

Comment: No it is just adding 1 to bar count.. the count I need for first candle should be 1. Here this code is counting bar right from day when the security was started trading i.e right from year 1999

Comment: @Shubhz Could you elaborate? Because Luc's code behaves according to your description. Maybe you want to calculate bars from the start of current session? Or what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @Michel_T. Yaaa that's what I'm looking for... The first bar of the session should be numbered 1. I don't want to count the bars of previous sessions... It should be like new session, new bar ,new count. Thank you!

Comment: Look at my answer - I think this is what you are looking for.